# Does prior COVID infection increase or decrease mortality on COVID reinfection?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, immune-system, infection, mortality-rate

One [recent large scale study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9671810/) found that a prior COVID infection doubles your risk of dying when you later catch a subsequent COVID infection.

This study followed 5 million people in the Veterans Affairs healthcare database for a 6-month period after their infection, and found their risk of death on a reinfection was twice the risk they had on their primary infection (and this increase in risk on reinfection occurred irrespective of vaccine status, but of course those vaccinated have a much lower baseline of risk to begin with).

Figure 3 from the study indicates the chances of death by any cause is actually slightly higher in the 6 month post-acute phase, compared to during the acute phase of the infection. We know already from other studies such as [this one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8938267/) that in the year after catching COVID, you are at higher risk of dying from heart attacks.

Yet seemingly to contradict the above finding, studies such as [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8786677/) indicate that prior COVID infection reduce the risk of death from reinfection by 61% (but the study only noted death during a shorter time interval of 28 days after testing positive). [This study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8824301/) also notes that the risk of death was reduced in SARS-CoV-2 reinfections versus primary infection.

Am I right in thinking that although prior infection may reduce your chances of death during the acute phase of any subsequent reinfections, the net effect of prior infection is to increase your chances of death after any reinfections, because lots of people who catch COVID are dying months after recovering from the acute infection?

Comment: "One recent large scale study found that a prior COVID infection doubles your risk of dying when you later catch a subsequent COVID infection" - where are you seeing this? It doesn't seem like what this paper is saying at all.

Comment: It says this in the abstract: "Compared to no reinfection, reinfection contributed additional risks of death (hazard ratio (HR) = 2.17)".

Comment: That means people who got infected again had a higher risk than people who didn't get reinfected. Everyone got sick once and survived, and now you're comparing people who got sick again to people who didn't. It's asking "is a second infection dangerous?" not "is a second infection worse than a first".

Comment: Yes I know. But many people, especially antivaxers, claim that natural immunity from a prior infection will help protect you from death in any further COVID infections that you might catch in future. However this Veterans Affairs study appears to show the opposite: that having had a prior infection increases your risk of death in any subsequent COVID infections.

Comment: No, that's not what it says. It just says that having a prior infection does not protect you entirely from future infections. It does not compare the risks of a second infection to risks of a first; it compares people who get a second infection to people who didn't and says you're better off not getting infected again. Not the same thing.

Comment: Statistically, everyone has their own personal baseline risk of death when they first catch COVID. In older people and the unvaccinated, and those with underlying health issues, that baseline risk is higher. If the baseline risk of death is R for your first infection, then this Veterans Affairs study found that your risk of death increases to 2 x R on your second infection.

Comment: You might like to read this Reuters article about the Veterans Affairs study: https://www.reuters.com/business/healthcare-pharmaceuticals/repeat-covid-is-riskier-than-first-infection-study-finds-2022-11-10/

Comment: Hmm, I may need to take a closer look at the paper, then - their methodology is not immediately clear to me.